# Fallback handler could not load library libc.dll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll

I am able to run my Unity game in my Editor without any error. However, when I build the game for Windows (any architecture) as shown below I get some errors printed in the "output_log.txt" text file generated by the game.

[image]

> Fallback handler could not load library C:/...../chem
>   build/ChemOCrypt-PC/ChemOCrypt-PC_Data/Mono/libc
>
> Fallback handler could not load library C:/...../chem
>   build/ChemOCrypt-PC/ChemOCrypt-PC_Data/Mono/libc.dll
>
> Fallback handler could not load library C:/...../chem
>   build/ChemOCrypt-PC/ChemOCrypt-PC_Data/Mono/libc

I am using several external libraries in my project, but none of them is causing any error in my editor. Further there is no folder called `mono` at the folder location `ChemOCrypt-PC_Data` (`ChemOCrypt-PC` is the game build location). I am not sure if this will affect my game or not, or how to fix it. Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: Are these external libraries in the plugins folder?

Comment: No, they are not in the plugin folder.

Comment: well, all external libraries et al should be there (it should be Plugins just to confirm)

Comment: one of my external lib is `Assets\bayesserver-8.3\DotNet\Standard20` which contains tonnes of dlls. and other one is `\Assets\Affdex\Plugins` which contains some other folders+scripts+dlls.

Comment: Things start breaking when I move the stuff to plugins folder, I guess I will live with this error instead.